# Template class with a non template base class

Tags: c++

I would like to know the exact compiler behavior that produces this error.

Have a look at this code.

```
class Base_class
{
public:
  Base_class();
};

Base_class::Base_class()
{
  //Here it says multiple definitions (If I define the contructor outside)
  //If I define this inside class no error 
  //Or if I make the base class templated no error
  //Also if this is in .cpp it works.
}

template<typename T>
class Temp_derived_class:Base_class
{
public:
  Temp_derived_class();

  int *i;
};

template<typename T>
Temp_derived_class<T>::Temp_derived_class()
{
  i = new int[5];
}
```

Here it says multiple definitions (If I define the contructor outside)
If I define this inside class no error 
Or if I make the base class templated no error
Also if this is in .cpp it works.

Cheers,
CB

Comment: It is like with any non-inline, non-template function: if you define it in the header, you get multiple definition errors. The template is just a distraction here.

Answer (score 4):

All used functions must have exactly one definition in the program, or be inline. By putting a non-inline definition in a header, you usually end up with multiple definitions, which is an error.

You can either:

- Declare the constructor `inline`, or
- Move the definition into a source file, or
- Move the definition into the class definition.

Function templates, and member functions defined inside the class definition, are implicitly inline, which is why there isn't a similar problem with the class template's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

When you put a function definition in a header, every translation unit that includes that header gets its own definition of the function. The [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) says that every name can have at most one definition in the whole program.

There are exceptions, though. In case of functions, there can be more definitions if the functions is marked `inline` and all definitions consist of same sequence of tokens. Member functions defined inside the class are implicitly inline and so are templates.

So, in addition to the workaround you've already found, you can also mark the constructor inline:

```
inline Base_class::Base_class()
{
}
```

Comment: Just to emphasize, it doesn't matter whether the non.-template is used as a base or whatever. Just whether that function is inline, and one way to get inline is to define inside the `class`.

Answer (score 0):

A template class with a non-template base class should be written inline to avoid compiler confusion. All the core logic should be in the base class and the template is just there to make casting easier.

i.e.

```
template<typename T>
class Temp_derived_class:Base_class
{
public:

    Temp_derived_class()
    {
      i = new int[5];
    }

  int *i;
};
```

Comment: The problem is with the *non*-template constructor. Any function template is implicitly inline, so there is no "compiler confusion" there.